# javascript follow html input fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Just like how I can track mouse position and follow with some animation, I wish to follow a user through various input fields on the form.

A normal html form comprising input fields, select fields, radio buttons, check boxes etc.

As a user changes input field by tab or mouse click etc, I wish to use an animation to follow them from form field to field.

So in summary, can I detrmine the x,y of the currently focused form field.

Comment: Sure its possible to track when user click on intput. You can use click event.

Comment: What do you mean by `follow them with a helper animation`? Are you want to show them tool tip? Are you want to show them a "flying" div? Please be more specify in what that you want that gonna happen.

Comment: Are you using jquery

Comment: what you meant? `follow them with a helper animation` as Mosh Feu said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the jquery library you can use the [`.mousemove(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) function which looks something like this

```
$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
  msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
});
```

Target is the id of the html element you want to track the mouse within and log is where the result is displayed 
Also to track cursor you could use the [`.keypress(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) it works similar to above code. Details can be found on the [jquery api site](http://api.jquery.com).